# AngularJS Domain model object

Tags: json, angularjs, object, model

This is a question for AngularJS developers, what is the best practice for the domain model objects ? File structure ? Class definition ? Modules ?

This will be mainly used for REST web services to translate JSON <-> Domain, is there any tool to convert Java domain classes into Javascript classes ?

I will certainly use $http for the REST api, maybe we can link domain objects directly on a $http service module ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I am using GSON for convert class to JSON.

It is so easy;

- Create a base class like Base.class
- Insert add your objects to this class
- And convert to JSON like;

  ```
  DataObject obj = new DataObject();
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = gson.toJson(obj);
  ```

[JAR](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&) and [More Info](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)...

Comment: This is something at back-end side only, I am looking for a solution on front-end ( angular) as well...

Comment: Why do you send your Java classes to front-end. Just send Json.

Comment: I know but I wanted to map JSON response into structured objects.

Comment: Create your JSON structure like Java Class (i mean same struct and and names) then you can map them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `$resource` it will return javascript objects to you. Otherwise `$http` will return a javascript object representation of the JSON data.

Comment: you might want to use console.log(obj) to see what's being returned.

Comment: Is it possible to return javascript objects using $http ? I want to use $http instead of $resource because $resource does not provide correct promises implementation... ( I already searched over google but I did not find any correct solution )

Comment: If your web service returns a JSON object `$http` should take this and turn it into a javascript object with the same structure. as I say, try using console.log to see what you get.

Comment: Although (and I don't want to push `$resource` too much) have you checkout out `$promise` from `$resource`. You can use it like this: `return resourceService.get({ id: yourID }).$promise.then(function(result) {
                    return result;
                });`

Comment: I tried before but I didnt get working, thats hwy I got back to $http.

Comment: Please can you post up the contents of the return, either outputting it onto a page and copy and pasting it or screen grabbing a view from the console window from a console.log.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using normal JS class files with .protoype for methods.

I was wondering if a tool exist converting Java classes into Javascript classes but this is another topic I guess.